# Transition between View Controllers with button (UIPageViewController Items)

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have 2 UIViewControllers as items of UIPageViewController. It works well for slide, but i want to move from pageOne to pageTwo with button's action. How i can do that?

Here is my code and storyboard preview:

Contents of Pager.swift :

```
import UIKit

class Pager: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate
{
var viewsArray: [UIViewController] = []

var pageOne: UIViewController = UIViewController()
var pageTwo: UIViewController = UIViewController()

var currentIndex = 0
var previousIndex = 0
var nextIndex = 0

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    pageOne = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageOne"))!
    pageTwo = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageTwo"))!

    viewsArray.append(pageOne)
    viewsArray.append(pageTwo)

    setViewControllers([pageOne], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    currentIndex = viewsArray.index(of: viewController)!
    if currentIndex == 1
    {
        return nil
    }
    else
    {
        nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % viewsArray.count)
        return viewsArray[nextIndex]
    }
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    currentIndex = viewsArray.index(of: viewController)!
    if currentIndex == 0
    {
        return nil
    }
    else
    {
        previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % viewsArray.count)
        return viewsArray[previousIndex]
    }
}


func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{
    return viewsArray.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{
    return 0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Contents of PageOne.swift :

```
import UIKit

class PageOne: UIViewController
{
var pager = Pager()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func forwardButton(_ sender: Any)
{
    pager.setViewControllers([pager.pageOne], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to write below line

```
pageController?.setViewControllers([YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

give proper direction either forward or reverse based on which controller you are at

hope this will help you

You need to pass pager to your both viewcontrollers

```
pageOne.pager = self
pageTwo.pager = self
```

Comment: Like this?
    @IBAction func forwardButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        pager.setViewControllers([pager.pageOne], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
---
I have update question body

Comment: updated my answer. you need to pass pager reference to your viewcontroller